# Does git concern about git repositories in git repositories?

Tags: git, repository, recursion

How does git handle a pure git repository in another git repository?

```
/prjA
/prjA/.git
/prjA/prjB
/prjA/prjB/.git
```

Is `/prjA/prjB/.git` stored as all other files in `prjA`, or can git optimize it to save memory or CPU?

Comment: I think this question should be rather asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think it fits to both, but feel free to move it...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you had `prjA` then you added `prjB` then you won't be able to add `prjB`'s /.git to your repository, only you can add and commit new files that prjB contained. In that case, the history of prjB will be lost.

If you need to keep repository inside repository, I would suggest to use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.